# Trouble parsing JSON data in Python3

Tags: python, json

Needing assistance getting the score value from

```
{
    "name": "Apdex",
    "timeslices": [
          {
            "from": "2020-01-15T19:49:00+00:00",
            "to": "2020-01-15T19:50:00+00:00",
            "values": {
              "score": 0.94,
              "s": 136000,
              "t": 9440,
              "f": 4510,
              "count": 150107,
              "value": 0.94,
              "threshold": 0.5,
              "threshold_min": 0.5
            }
      }
}
```

This is the `JSON` as I have received it from an API call to [New Relic API Explore](https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/137661621/metrics/data.json).

```
{
  "metric_data": {
    "from": "2020-01-15T19:51:32+00:00",
    "to": "2020-01-15T19:53:02+00:00",
    "metrics_not_found": [],
    "metrics_found": [
      "Apdex",
      "EndUser/Apdex"
    ],
    "metrics": [
      {
        "name": "Apdex",
        "timeslices": [
          {
            "from": "2020-01-15T19:49:00+00:00",
            "to": "2020-01-15T19:50:00+00:00",
            "values": {
              "score": 0.94,
              "s": 136000,
              "t": 9440,
              "f": 4510,
              "count": 150107,
              "value": 0.94,
              "threshold": 0.5,
              "threshold_min": 0.5
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "EndUser/Apdex",
        "timeslices": [
          {
            "from": "2020-01-15T19:49:00+00:00",
            "to": "2020-01-15T19:50:00+00:00",
            "values": {
              "score": 1.0,
              "s": 0,
              "t": 0,
              "f": 0,
              "count": 0,
              "value": null,
              "threshold": 7.0,
              "threshold_min": 7.0
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm having problems getting the correct score to output.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the code that is not doing what you want and its output?

Comment: Could you clarify what the "correct" score is, in the JSON you provided? Also it would be useful to have the code you've tried.

Comment: little-dude The correct score is the one with the value of 0.94

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is a json in variable `input`

```
import json

data = json.loads(input)
result = data['metric_data']['metrics']
```

This will give you a list, if you want the exact one in your question, you could filter within a list comprehension:

```
final_result = [score for score in result if score['name'] == 'Apdex']
slices = final_result[0]['timeslices']
values = [slice['values']['score'] for slice in slices]
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for exactly.  It is returning a string: [{'name': 'Apdex', 'timeslices': [{'from': '2020-01-15T21:20:00+00:00', 'to': '2020-01-15T21:21:00+00:00', 'values': {'score': 0.94, 's': 52900, 't': 4460, 'f': 1270, 'count': 58631, 'value': 0.94, 'threshold': 0.5, 'threshold_min': 0.059}}]}] . All I am looking to return is the value of 0.94 from the score.

Comment: this is also giving an error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {
  "metric_data": {
    "from": "2020-01-15T19:51:32+00:00",
    "to": "2020-01-15T19:53:02+00:00",
    "metrics_not_found": [],
    "metrics_found": [
      "Apdex",
      "EndUser/Apdex"
    ],
    "metrics": [
      {
        "name": "Apdex",
        "timeslices": [
          {
            "from": "2020-01-15T19:49:00+00:00",
            "to": "2020-01-15T19:50:00+00:00",
            "values": {
              "score": 0.94,
              "s": 136000,
              "t": 9440,
              "f": 4510,
              "count": 150107,
              "value": 0.94,
              "threshold": 0.5,
              "threshold_min": 0.5
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "EndUser/Apdex",
        "timeslices": [
          {
            "from": "2020-01-15T19:49:00+00:00",
            "to": "2020-01-15T19:50:00+00:00",
            "values": {
              "score": 1.0,
              "s": 0,
              "t": 0,
              "f": 0,
              "count": 0,
              "value": None,
              "threshold": 7.0,
              "threshold_min": 7.0
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
for m in d['metric_data']['metrics']:
    print(m['timeslices'][0]['values']['score'])
```

Comment: This is close to what I need, however it is giving me both scores  the "score": 0.94 is the one I need, but it is also printing the "score": 1.0 which I do not want.